# Ошибка в подсветке синтаксиса в коде для C#

Tags: поддержка, форматирование, редактор

В редакторе сообщений, если код на C#, и если в коде поставить `@` перед началом строки, в которой есть `\`, то весь последующий код посвечивается неправильно.
На скриншоте видно, что текст сообщения после `@` подсвечен как строка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UP:**

Также [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477796/196972) в с# не подсвечивается `get;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нашел возможный общий фикс, чуть обновил ответ. если еще для какого-то языка будут проблемы с подсветкой - пишите.

Comment: @PashaPash в c# еще `get;` не подсвечивается -- добавил в пост.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема в том, что подсветка иногда не угадывает целевой язык (C#/Java). Это достаточно хорошо видно в вопросах по SQL - там подсветка не срабатывает почти никогда.

Чинится добавлением хинта для подсветки непосредственно перед кодом (без отступа, и с пустой строкой между хинтом и кодом):

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
```

или

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
```

пример:

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

var d = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// тут загружаем html ...

foreach (var img in Images(d, "/img/items/")) {
    Console.WriteLine(img.Url.Segments.Last() + " " + img.Title);
    // скачиваем рисунок с сайта и записываем в файл
    using (var c = new WebClient())
      c.DownloadFile(img.Url, @"c:\temp\" + img.Title + ".jpg");
}

static IEnumerable<Img> Images(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc, string urlContains) {
  foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")) {
    var t = img.ParentNode.Attributes["title"];
    var s = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
    if (s.Contains(urlContains))
      yield return new Img { Url = new Uri(s), Title = (t != null ? t.Value : "") };
  }
}

class Img {
    public string Title;
    public Uri Url;
}
```

для сравнения, тот же код без хинта:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

var d = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// тут загружаем html ...

foreach (var img in Images(d, "/img/items/")) {
    Console.WriteLine(img.Url.Segments.Last() + " " + img.Title);
    // скачиваем рисунок с сайта и записываем в файл
    using (var c = new WebClient())
      c.DownloadFile(img.Url, @"c:\temp\" + img.Title + ".jpg");
}

static IEnumerable<Img> Images(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc, string urlContains) {
  foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")) {
    var t = img.ParentNode.Attributes["title"];
    var s = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
    if (s.Contains(urlContains))
      yield return new Img { Url = new Uri(s), Title = (t != null ? t.Value : "") };
  }
}

class Img {
    public string Title;
    public Uri Url;
}
```

почему в режиме lang-cs не подсвечивается `using` - загадка.

**UP:**

Откопал в инструментах модератора указывать язык подсветки по умолчанию сразу для всех вопросов по метке (прощай, lang-sql!). Прописал для [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) и [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Если для других языков регулярно наблюдаются глюки с неправильной подсветкой - отписывайтесь или в комментариях, или отдельными постами на мете - или я, или другой модератор исправим.

Comment: Ну почему ж загадка. [Баг в prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/prettify.js#L186), видимо :)

Comment: Странно, язык должно было бы угадать, исходя из тегов вопроса.

Comment: Кстати, анекдот. В мобильном клиенте подсветка блоков кода идентичная (неправильная).